# How to work on latest sdk and support older ones

Tags: android

I need to suppoert api level 10, and working with latest sdk to provide new device features (only if sdk of device is new).
on manifest I choose min version 10.

The problem is that the application is not installed succesfully on the old sdk devices. 
Whne I debug on those devices it works, The installation of signed aok fails.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application uses any API's that are not available on older Android versions, then you should try to use Support Libraries or just give up on those devices. If the application does run on older emulators in debug mode, then you can just change the `minSdkVersion` in the manifest to a lower one. Hope this helps.

Comment: As suggested you should support libraries http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Comment: Is there a way to figure why the installation fails?

Comment: @ChenKinnrot, It probably fails cause the minSdkVersion is too big.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your manifest file

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```